# Awkard behavior in Setting Next Step Programmatically Mat Stepper Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, typescript, frontend

I have a mat stepper in angular and when a user captures their peronal Info and Education History. When they leave the Personal infor Tab, I save whatever is there and proceed to the next step, Incase of an error, I return them back and display the error. I'm using onStepSelectionChange event change. This works Well.

Here is how I have handled the StepChange Event

```
  onStepSelectionChange(event: StepperSelectionEvent, PassedStepper: MatStepper) {

    this.showPreloader = true;
    // Get the index of the newly selected step
    const selectedIndex = event.selectedIndex;
    console.log('Selected Index', selectedIndex);
    console.log('Previously Selected Index', event.previouslySelectedIndex);

    const previouslySelectedIndex = event.previouslySelectedIndex;
    const selectedStep = event.selectedIndex;

    console.log({selectedIndex, previouslySelectedIndex, event})

    if (selectedIndex > 0 && previouslySelectedIndex === 0) {
        if(this.ApplicantPersonalInfo.invalid){
            this.ApplicantPersonalInfo.markAllAsTouched();
            this.showPreloader = false;
            return;
        }

        // Create Personal Info Object

        // If gender is not other set value of OtherGenderSpecification to null

        if (this.ApplicantPersonalInfo.value.Gender != 'Other') {
            this.ApplicantPersonalInfo.value.OtherGenderSpecification = null;
        }

        const personalInfo: PersononalInfoModel = {
            FirstName: this.ApplicantPersonalInfo.value.First_Name,
            LastName: this.ApplicantPersonalInfo.value.Last_Name,
            MiddleNamee: this.ApplicantPersonalInfo.value.Middle_Name,
            Gender: this.ApplicantPersonalInfo.value.Gender,
            MaritalStatus: this.ApplicantPersonalInfo.value.Marital_Status,
            DateOfBirth: this.ApplicantPersonalInfo.value.Birth_Date,
            Nationalityy: this.ApplicantPersonalInfo.value.Nationality,
            Nationality: this.ApplicantPersonalInfo.value.Nationality,
            County : this.ApplicantPersonalInfo.value.County,
            DisabilityCertificate: this.ApplicantPersonalInfo.value.DisabilityCertificate,
            Ethnic_Group: this.ApplicantPersonalInfo.value.Ethnic_Group,
            Profession: this.ApplicantPersonalInfo.value.Profession,
            Highest_Level_Of_Education: this.ApplicantPersonalInfo.value.Highest_Level_Of_Education,
            Address: this.ApplicantPersonalInfo.value.Address,
            Phone_No: this.ApplicantPersonalInfo.value.Phone_No,
            NCPWD : this.ApplicantPersonalInfo.value.NCPWD,
            AbledDifferent : this.ApplicantPersonalInfo.value.AbledDifferent,
            DisabilityDescription : this.ApplicantPersonalInfo.value.DisabilityDescription,
            PassportNo : this.ApplicantPersonalInfo.value.PassportNo,
            PassportExpiryDate : this.ApplicantPersonalInfo.value.PassportExpiryDateExpiry,
            PassportIssueDate : this.ApplicantPersonalInfo.value.PassportIssueDateIssued,
            PermitNo : this.ApplicantPersonalInfo.value.PermitNo,
            PermitExpiryDate : this.ApplicantPersonalInfo.value.PermitExpiryDateExpiry,
            PermitIssueDate : this.ApplicantPersonalInfo.value.PermitIssueDateIssued,
            IdNumber : this.ApplicantPersonalInfo.value.IdNumber,
            HomeCounty : this.ApplicantPersonalInfo.value.HomeCounty,
            Title : this.ApplicantPersonalInfo.value.Title,
            Disability : this.ApplicantPersonalInfo.value.DisabilityDescription,
            OtherGenderSpecification: this.ApplicantPersonalInfo.value.OtherGenderSpecification,
        }
        console.log('Personal Info', personalInfo);
        this.recruitmentService.savePersonalInfo(personalInfo).subscribe(
            (data: any) => {
                if(data){
                    this.isThisStepDone = true;
                    // PassedStepper.selectedIndex = selectedIndex+1;
                    this.showPreloader = false;
                    // PassedStepper.next();
                    console.log('Personal Info Saved', data);
                    this.showPreloader = false;
                    this.showSuccessUsingToast("Personal Information Saved Successfully");
                }else{
                    this.showErrorUsingToast("Unable To Save Personal Informatio");
                    this.showPreloader = false;
                    // event.selectedIndex = previouslySelectedIndex;

                    PassedStepper.previous();
                }

            },
            (error: any) => {
                this.showErrorUsingToast(error.error.Message);
                console.log('Personal Info Error', error);
                this.showPreloader = false;
                event.selectedIndex = previouslySelectedIndex;
                // PassedStepper.previous();
            }
        )
    }

    if(previouslySelectedIndex ==1){ // More Info has changed
        if(this.MorePersonalInfoForm.invalid){
            this.MorePersonalInfoForm.markAllAsTouched();
        }

        // Create More Personal Info Object

        const morePersonalInfo: MorePersonalInfoModel = {
            DateOfBirth: this.MorePersonalInfoForm.value.Birth_Date,
            PermitNo: this.MorePersonalInfoForm.value.PermitNo,
            PermitExpiryDate: this.MorePersonalInfoForm.value.PermitExpiryDateExpiry,
            PermitIssueDate: this.MorePersonalInfoForm.value.PermitIssueDateIssued,
            AbledDifferent: this.MorePersonalInfoForm.value.AbledDifferent,
            DisabilityDescription   : this.MorePersonalInfoForm.value.AbledDifferentSpecification,
            NCPWD: this.MorePersonalInfoForm.value.NCPWD,
            PassportExpiryDate: this.MorePersonalInfoForm.value.PassportExpiryDateExpiry,
            PassportIssueDate: this.MorePersonalInfoForm.value.PassportIssueDateIssued,
        }

        this.recruitmentService.saveMorePersonalInfo(morePersonalInfo).subscribe(
            (data: any) => {
                if(data){
                    this.isThisStepDone = true;
                } else{
                    PassedStepper.selectedIndex = selectedIndex;
                    // PassedStepper.previous();
                }
            },
            (error: any) => {
                console.log('More Personal Info Error', error);
                PassedStepper.selectedIndex = selectedIndex;
                // PassedStepper.previous();
            }
        );


    }


    this.showPreloader = false;

    // event.selectedIndex = selectedIndex;


}
```

My problem is on the Education Qualifications. I want to remain on the same page after saving because the user can have multiple of them. What my system is doing is once it's done saving, I'm taken back to Step 0.

Here is my Code that submits the Qualification

```
   saveEducationQualification(PassedStepper: MatStepper) {
    // this.stepper = PassedStepper;
    if(this.EducationInformation.invalid){
        this.EducationInformation.markAllAsTouched();
        this.showPreloader = false;
        return;
    }
    let activeIndex = PassedStepper.selectedIndex;
    console.log('Active Index', activeIndex);
    // console.log("This Sterpper ",this.stepper);


    console.log('CurrentEmploymentInfo', this.CurrentEmploymentInfo.value);
    this.showPreloader = true;
    // Create Education Info Object

    const educationInfo: EducationQualifications = {
        Instituition: this.EducationInformation.value.Instituition,
        Qualification: this.EducationInformation.value.Qualification,
        StartDate: this.EducationInformation.value.StartDate,
        EndDate: this.EducationInformation.value.ToDate,
        Description: this.EducationInformation.value.Description,
        Grade: this.EducationInformation.value.Grade,

    }
    console.log('Education Info Form', this.EducationInformation);

    this.recruitmentService.SaveEducationQualifications(educationInfo).subscribe(
        (data: any) => {
            if(data){
                console.log('Education Info Saved', data);
                this.showEducationModal = false;
                this.showPreloader = false;
                this.hideDialog();
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.EducationInformation.reset();
                    console.log('Education Info Saved', data);
                    console.log({PassedStepper, activeIndex, });
                    PassedStepper.selectedIndex = activeIndex;
                }, 900);

            }else{
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.showPreloader = false;
                    this.hideDialog();
                    this.EducationInformation.reset();
                    console.log({PassedStepper, activeIndex, });
                    // Don't go to next step. Stay on the same step
                    PassedStepper.selectedIndex = activeIndex;
                }, 900);

            }

        }, (error: any) => {
            console.log('Education Info Error', error);
            this.showPreloader = false;
            this.hideDialog();
            this.EducationInformation.reset();
            // PassedStepper.selectedIndex = activeIndex;
            console.log({PassedStepper, activeIndex});

        }
    );

}
```

Education Qualification is step No 2.

On my console result. Seleted Step is 2 but I'm being redirected to step 0.

Here is my console result

```
_linear
: 
true
_orientation
: 
"horizontal"
_selectedIndex
: 
2
```

What could i be doin wrong or Missing?